# How to build a string with XSLT?

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0, concatenation

I have this XML snippet

```
<MediaTypes>
  <DVD>true</DVD>
  <HDDVD>false</HDDVD>
  <BluRay>true</BluRay>
</MediaTypes>
```

And I want to create an output that looks like this

```
DVD / Blu-ray
```

or like this

```
DVD
```

or like this

```
DVD / HD-DVD / Blu-ray
```

depending on the true/false states

But I'm a total beginner in the XSLT game. :-/

Here's a snippet of the full XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="Windows-1252"?>
<Collection xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <DVD>
    <ProfileTimestamp>2012-06-07T05:20:51Z</ProfileTimestamp>
    <ID>0044005507027.5</ID>
    <MediaTypes>
      <DVD>true</DVD>
      <HDDVD>false</HDDVD>
      <BluRay>false</BluRay>
    </MediaTypes>
    <UPC>0-044005-507027</UPC>
    <CollectionNumber>448</CollectionNumber>
    <CollectionType IsPartOfOwnedCollection="true">Owned</CollectionType>
    <Title>The Big Lebowski</Title>
    <DistTrait />
    <OriginalTitle />
    <CountryOfOrigin>United States</CountryOfOrigin>
    ...
  </DVD>
  <DVD>
     ...
  </DVD>
</Collection>
```

I tried to follow the advices given below (regarding the loop), but it doesn't seem to work.

This is the XSL I have so far (complete):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

    <xsl:template name="MediaTypes" match="MediaTypes">
        Test
        <xsl:for-each select="*[.='true']">            
            <xsl:value-of select="name()"/>
            <xsl:if test="position()!=last()">
                <xsl:text>/</xsl:text>
            </xsl:if>
        </xsl:for-each>        
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <html>
            <head>
                <title>DVD Profiler Double Dips</title>
            </head>
            <body>
                <div>
                    <h1>DVD Profiler Double Dips</h1>
                </div>
                <table border="1" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="0">
                    <tr>
                        <th>Title</th>
                        <th>Edition</th>
                        <th>Production Year</th>
                        <th>DVD /</th>
                        <th>Purchase Date</th>
                        <th>Collection Type</th>
                        <th>Original Title</th>
                        <th>Sort Title</th>
                    </tr>
                    <xsl:for-each select="/Collection/DVD">
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <xsl:value-of select="Title"/>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <xsl:if test="DistTrait != ''">
                                    <xsl:value-of select="DistTrait"/>
                                </xsl:if>
                                <xsl:if test="DistTrait = ''">
                                    &#160;
                                </xsl:if>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <xsl:if test="ProductionYear != ''">
                                    <xsl:value-of select="ProductionYear"/>
                                </xsl:if>
                                <xsl:if test="ProductionYear = ''">
                                    &#160;
                                </xsl:if>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <xsl:call-template name="MediaTypes" />
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                </table>
            </body>
        </html>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

But where

```
<xsl:call-template name="MediaTypes" />
```

is standing, only "Test" comes out

**Yay!**

You guys are awesome. Yes

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="MediaTypes"/>
```

Was my weapon of choice.

My final template looks like this:

```
<xsl:template name="MediaTypes" match="MediaTypes">
    <xsl:for-each select="*[.='true']">
        <xsl:value-of select="name()"/>
        <xsl:if test="position()!=last()">
            <xsl:text> / </xsl:text>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:for-each>
    <xsl:if test="CustomMediaType != ''">
        <xsl:if test="*[.='true']">
            <xsl:text> / </xsl:text>
        </xsl:if>
        <xsl:value-of select="CustomMediaType"/>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
```

*begins to understand how stuff works*

Thanks for all your help!

Comment: What version of XSLT?  Can you use 2.0 or are you limited to 1.0, and if 1.0 then what XSLT processor will you be using?

Comment: Uhm, so you want to use the elements and not their content as your output? That is a bit unconventional

Comment: @IanRoberts I want to put this XSL into the header of an XML file and then have any browser show me an HTML.

Comment: @EricHerlitz Is it? As I said, I'm an XSL noob. I come from the classic programming world. :-/

Comment: In that case the answer is 1.0 - to my knowledge there's no browser that implements 2.0 natively (and even if there were you'd need to stick to 1.0 to work on them all).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The question is rather trivial - the real problem is that you only show a snippet of the XML document. XSLT is very much context-dependent.

Here is a template to match any `<MediaTypes>` element and output the required string; hopefully you'll know how to incorporate it into your own stylesheet:

```
<xsl:template match="MediaTypes">
    <xsl:for-each select="*[.='true']">
        <xsl:value-of select="name()"/>
        <xsl:if test="position()!=last()">
            <xsl:text>/</xsl:text>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: I've tried that, but it doesn't seem to enter the for-each loop

I've entered this into my code

    <xsl:template name="MediaTypes" match="MediaTypes">
      <xsl:for-each select="*[.='true']">
   Test
          <xsl:value-of select="name()"/>
          <xsl:if test="position()!=last()">
              <xsl:text>/</xsl:text>
          </xsl:if>
      </xsl:for-each>

and later on when I need it, I wrote 

    <xsl:call-template name="MediaTypes" />

But the only output is "Test" :-(

Comment: @DeeJ.Doena you probably need to use `apply-templates` instead of `call-template` to make sure the context node is correct - with `<xsl:call-template name="MediaTypes"/>` the context node will remain at whatever it was at the point of the call, but with `<xsl:apply-templates select="path/to/MediaTypes"/>` it'll reset the context correctly to the MediaTypes element.

Comment: @DeeJ.Doena I suggest you edit your question to include your XSLT and the output you are hoping to get (as code).

Comment: @DeeJ.Doena As suggested by Ian Roberts, just add my template *as is* to your stylesheet, and replace `<xsl:call-template name="MediaTypes"/>` with `<xsl:apply-templates select="MediaTypes"/>`.

Answer (score 0):

I'd advice you to change the xml a bit

Here is an example

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" ?>
<MediaTypes>
    <Media name="DVD">true</Media>
    <Media name="HDDVD">false</Media>
    <Media name="BluRay">true</Media>
</MediaTypes>
```

This way you may write XPATH expressions like `//MediaTypes/Media`
However did @michael.hor257k write a nice solution, jacking this xml pattern into that would look like this

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:template match="//MediaTypes">
        <xsl:for-each select="*[.='true']">
            <xsl:value-of select="@name"/>
            <xsl:if test="position()!=last()">
                <xsl:text>/</xsl:text>
            </xsl:if>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This will render `DVD/BluRay`

Test here http://xslttest.appspot.com/

Comment: Thanks, but onfortunately the XML isn't mine :-/